# Can we install safari and edge webDriver on the docker?

Tags: selenium, docker, webdriver

I could install chrome and firefox webDriver on Docker, but I don't know if it is possible to do the same with safari and edge too.
So any one has an idea? if yes how to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker containerisation is limited to Linux OS containers only. This means no OS X nor Windows. So you can't run Safari nor Edge.

But you can add a vagrant vm browser (running Windows or OS X), and then connect them to your Selenium hub.

Answer (score 0):

There is no installation available for safari on docker. You can read the following issue for more details

https://github.com/aerokube/selenoid/issues/663